# Issue with loading jquery after bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to research before asking here, but I coun't find any answers. Just for context, I'm using old version of bootstrap `v2.0.2`. I doubled checked if my paths are correct, and they are.

[image]

This is the order of imported scripts that produce the errors above. If I load `bootstrap.min.js` first, I will get a different error.

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
   <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

   <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've tried to import `bootstrap.min.js` first, but this the error message I get, and I'm not sure why.

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
   <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
        
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

   <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

I expected it that this small change would resolve the issue, but it didn't.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use jQuery versions starting with 1.9 with Bootstrap 2.0.2.

jQuery 1.8.3 does work as shown below (note that jQuery must still be loaded before Bootstrap's JavaScript):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-J9QfbPuFlqGD2CYVCa6zn8/7PEgZnGpM5qtFOBZgwujjDnG5w5Fjx46YzqvIh/ORstcj7luStvvIHkisQi5SKw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.2/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-jv0RCzX/cFYIF5KkvheT4Xk06YMyEmYAJ8mxZ0pgzwHMgIdT/KGedWD2dK2modKDyaK6DSDwh6ptzTHtfJ0Nng==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" integrity="sha512-c4E36NNKxeFBnGTk/nFCssF4B7gXdZ9hqBnR0fec+DiZ7EnCB2RA42O8HPdgKHFnseb4s6ieQtmT8iksW+QfWw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. In terms of security, do you think its fine to use older version of jquery?

Comment: @xertz There shouldn't be security issues, but I would still recommend upgrading to a newer version of Bootstrap (the newest is 5.2 as of now, which doesn't require jQuery).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I prefer this (v2.0.2) style of bootstrap.